# Compiling GWEN with CodeBlocks

Tags: windows, user-interface, gcc, mingw, codeblocks

so, I'm trying to compile Gwen in Windows, for use with a project I have coming up. I downloaded the source from Garry's GitHub, and followed his instructions on building the compilation before importing it to Code::Blocks to compile. I import the .cbp file, start compiling, and after a few minutes I get:

Error: '_asm' was not declared in this scope.

The error comes from some code after a line containing #ifdef _WIN32.

Exact file: gwen.cpp, line 49.

More information: 
OS: Windows 7 64bit.
Compiler: Latest gcc from the MinGW, 4.7.2 (MinGW32)

Comment: GWEN can't be compiled with GCC because it uses many MSVC specific features (Believe me I tried!)

Comment: Have you tried Gwork? https://github.com/billyquith/GWork

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because MinGW doesn't understand the assembler, it should be `asm` for that compiler. I think this is cause by using `_WIN32` instead of `WIN32`. The former is the platform and the latter is API.

Try changing it to:

```
    void AssertCheck(bool b, const char* strMsg)
    {
        if (!b)
        {
            Msg("Assert: %s\n", strMsg);
#ifdef WIN32
            MessageBoxA(NULL, strMsg, "Assert", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
            _asm { int 3 }
#endif
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Alternatively you could try [Gwork](https://github.com/billyquith/GWork), which is a tidied up version of GWEN.

Comment: Sorry for waiting so long to reply! I sort of forgot about posting this. I never got around to trying it, as we changed some ideas and ended up not needing GWEN. I appreciate the help!